# How to get left and right aligned buttons to be responsive (displayed one after other)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

Left and right aligned buttons should be responsive. I tried below code, unable to get responsive like if we reduce the resolutions buttons should be displayed one by one (vertical).

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

.leftAlign{
  float:left;
}
.rightAlign{
  float:right;
}

.btns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: -0.5em;
  margin-left: -0.5em;

  .btn {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 32rem) {
  .btns {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="btns leftAlign">
  <button class="btn btn--subtle">Left</button>
</div>

<div class="btns rightAlign">
  <button class="btn btn--primary">Righ1</button>
  <button class="btn btn--primary">Right2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: "Responsive" isn't a descriptive term. Please revise to describe your goals better. Also, don't mix floats with flexbox. Floats are rarely useful in the modern web.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve everything only using flex, don't need to use floats:

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.btns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

@media (min-width: 32rem) {
  .btns {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btns">
    <button class="btn btn--subtle">Left</button>
  </div>

  <div class="btns">
    <button class="btn btn--primary">Right1</button>
    <button class="btn btn--primary">Right2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```